# PHP: preg_replace the # sign

Tags: php, regex

I'm looping through a list of words being replaced using preg_replace. Here is the code I'm using:

```
foreach ( $words->Reserved as $reserved )
    $code = preg_replace( ( '/\b(' . $reserved . ')\b/' ), ( '<cs_reserved>' . $reserved . '</cs_reserved>' ), $code );
```

The expression used above works perfectly, unless `$reserved` contains a `#` sign. I tried using brackets (as seen above), and that did not help.

I'm not very good at regex, so the above may not be ideal, but it does exactly what it needs to do for my project.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `preg_quote`

```
$code = preg_replace( ( '/\b(' . preg_quote($reserved) . ')\b/' ), ( '<cs_reserved>' . $reserved . '</cs_reserved>' ), $code );
```

Comment: +1 for answer, and "oh, neat" effect. Didn't even know that existed but good to know.

Comment: You should add `/` as the second argument.

Comment: It appears to have no effect... even with alex's suggestion.